# Why i cant save and check session in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning nodejs and I want to check if user is logged in by checking session.login value but when session.login is created and then user is redirected to main page, session.login is again undefined.
emit 'logged' is just redirecting user to the dashboard but dashboard checks if session.login exists, it shows undefined and user is redirected again to the login page.

```
var app = require('express')(); //load and initialize express
var http = require('http').Server(app); //create http server
var io = require('socket.io')(http); //add socket to http server
var path = require('path') //initialize path module
var port = 3000; //define port
var mysql = require('mysql'); //load mysql module
var session = require('express-session'); //sessions module
var login; //login
var md5 = require('md5');

//connecting to the database
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'chat'
});

con.connect((error) => {
    if(error) console.log('Error with database connection.');
    else console.log("Connected to the database!");
});

//define default path
app.use(require('express').static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

//session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'randomstringhere',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {

    }
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.login) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
        console.log("Someone has joined to the server.");

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            //login
            socket.on('login', (login, password) => {
                con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="'+login+'" AND password="'+md5(password)+'"', (error, results, fields) => {
                    if (error) console.log('Error');
                    if (results[0]) {
                        req.session.login = results[0].login;
                        console.log(req.session.login+": Succesfully logged.");
                        req.session.save();
                        socket.emit('logged', 'You will be logged, please wait!');//redirects to /dashboard
                    }
                    else {
                        socket.emit('cant login', 'Login or password incorrect!');
                        console.log("Incorrect login or password.");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});

app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.login) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
        console.log(req.session.login + " has joined to the server.");

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            socket.on('message', (msg) => {
                io.emit('message', req.session.login + ": " + msg);
                console.log(req.session.login + ": " + msg);
            });

            //logout
            socket.on('logout', () => {
                socket.emit('logging out');
                req.session.destroy();
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: Rather than using socket to login, create an API and use that to log in the user. That will work :)

Comment: Sessions work with cookies. Can you set a cookie with websockets at first place? I doubt you can. You need to use another strategy, like jwt or separate login/logout endpoints from your websocket endpoints. Or redirect the user to another page with javascript inside the browser after log in.